# Como verificar se um polígono é regular ou convexo

Tags: r, geometria

Existe alguma função no R que verifique se um polígono é regular ou não e alguma que verifique se ele é convexo ou não?

Caso uma ou outra resposta seja não, alguma ideia? Como pensei:

```
#Por exemplo um quadrilátero, a primeira coluna é x e a segunda coluna é y.
quadrilatero = matrix(c(0,2,-7,1,4,3, 4,5), ncol = 2)

#o input (poligono) tem duas colunas obrigatoriamente 
verifica_regular = function(poligono){
  distancias = apply(poligono, 1, dist)
  if(distancias == distancias[1]) return(T)
  else return(F)
}
verifica_regular(quadrilatero)
```

Mas a função `dist` dentro do `apply` calcula a diferença entre um valor e o valor da coluna seguinte.

Para verificar a convexidade não tenho nem ideia.

Comment: Como você define o polígono? Matriz de duas colunas (X, Y), e cada linha contendo um dos seus vértices? O primeiro vértice é repetido no final (para "fechar" o polígono), ou isso é implícito? Se você colocar um exemplo completo [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), vai ficar mais fácil de receber respostas.

Comment: E para saber a convexidade, você pode calcular todos os ângulos a partir dos conjuntos de 3 vértices adjacentes, baseado em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points, e se todos forem menores que 180, o seu polígono será convexo.

Comment: @carlosfigueira coloquei um exemplo.

Comment: Wagner, o Carlos já te deu a resposta quanto ao polígono ser regular. Sugiro que faça uma pergunta diferente sobre ser convexo, caso você não consiga resolver com as dicas do Carlos. Provavelmente ele vai responder rapidinho. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para verificar se o polígono é regular, você precisa da distância de todos os pontos, inclusive do "último" ponto do seu polígono para o "primeiro" - nos exemplos do código abaixo, se você não "fechar" o polígono, você terá um resultado incorreto no primeiro caso.

E nesse caso você não precisa da função `apply`. `dist` já te dá a distância entre todos os pontos, então o que você precisa é pegar a diagonal da parte inferior (ou superior) da matriz que ela te retorna.

E como @JJoao notou, a condição de lados iguais é necessária, mas não suficiente para que o polígono seja regular. Todos os seus ângulos precisam ser idênticos também. Uma forma de se verificar isso, dado que os lados são iguais, é verificar que o centro do polígono é equidistante de todos os pontos. O código atualizado está abaixo.

```
verifica_lados_iguais <- function(poligono) {
    no_vertices <- nrow(poligono)
    poligono_fechado <- rbind(poligono, poligono[1])
    distancias <- diag(as.matrix(dist(poligono_fechado))[1:no_vertices, 2:(no_vertices + 1)])
    lados_iguais <- all(distancias == distancias[1])
}

verifica_equidistancia_centro <- function(poligono) {
    c <- apply(poligono, 2, sum) / nrow(poligono)
    dist_centro <- apply(poligono, 1, function(p) sqrt((c[1] - p[1])^2 + (c[2] - p[2])^2))
    equidistanteCentro <- all((abs(dist_centro - dist_centro[1]) < 0.00001))
}

verifica_regular <- function(poligono) {
    regular <- verifica_lados_iguais(poligono) &&
        verifica_equidistancia_centro(poligono)
}

print(quadrilatero <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
print(verifica_regular(quadrilatero))
print(quadrado <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
print(verifica_regular(quadrado))
print(losango <- matrix(c(0, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, -1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
print(verifica_regular(losango))
```

Comment: Carlos, normalmente a definição de poligono regular implica tambem angulos iguais. Exemplo uma casa desenhada com 5 lados iguais e angulos 90 90 120 60 120 é marcada como regular.

Comment: Tem razão - a lógica original iria identificar um losango (não quadrado) como regular. Atualizando a resposta...

Comment: Carlos, Excelente +1